# How to query an API greater than less than

Tags: api

Basic question but couldn't find an answer to this.

There is fake API testing tool located here
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

When I add a query like this
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=4

I get a response

When I change the query to this
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId<4
it returns null

How would I query in the url userId that is less than 4?

Comment: you cannot do that because the api is not designed that way.The work around is to get all the userids and then filter them by your requirement

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to encode the '<' sign as a special character with its hexadecimal code ('<' is 3c) so your query becomes:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId%3c4

Any special character in a url can be coded as % followed by its two-digit hexadecimal code.

EDIT: After trying the URL with my change, I was able to get the '<' sign decoded as I mentioned above.  However, it doesn't seem to provide the expected return (all user IDs less than 4).  It returns more user IDs than this. Maybe need to check the API docs to make sure that 'userId<4' is a correct field definition.